# Change page content based on condition Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I  would like to change to homepage of a wordpress website depending on the role of the user who is logged in.

For the simple case ( i.e. whether a user is logged in or not ) I have tried using the function is_user_logged_in()

the code is as below:

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    // Include the page content template.
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                        comments_template();
                    }
                endwhile;
            }else{
                echo "you are logged in";
            }
```

But the problem is that it changes the content in the each and every page. I would like to do that for a particular page only.. ( i.e. homepage ). How do i do that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it you would have to add another condition(s), e.g. for the homepage:

```
if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_home()){

...

}
```

And similarly for the other type of the content: `is_page()`, `is_category()`, `is_author()`, etc. Check out the docs [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

Comment: What if it is not the home page ?  suppose I do not have homepage but I have a particular page like xyz.com/newpage and we want to add condition for that page.

Answer (score -2):

check for the Id of the page and compare it to your wanted specific page
also you could set a category for the pages you want to alter and check for that